# My watchPosition function is not working correctly?

Tags: javascript, google-maps

```
function displayLocation(position) 
{
      user_lat = position.coords.latitude;
      user_long = position.coords.longitude;
      moveMarker(user_marker,user_lat,user_long); 
}

function displayError(error) 
{
alert("someting wrong"); 
}

function getMyLocation() 
{
if (navigator.geolocation)
    watchId = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(displayLocation, displayError,
{        frequency: 3000 } );
}
else 
{         
    setInterval(function(){alert("your device does not support Geolocation")},5000);  
}
```

}

So basicly I am using a marker and using watch position in conjunction with google maps api to move the marker to the users position. I have the whole thing working on a website if anyone want to see. 
udaapps.com. My watchPosition function is not working even when I move around. This is primarily for cellphone use, kind of a web app.

Answer (score 0):

Try specifing high accuracy in the options:

{ frequency: 3000, enableHighAccuracy: true }